# EndPointsModel query by ancestor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

how can I do a query by ancestor according to the user_id that I get from the token ?

This is my code:

```
class MyUserClass(EndPointModel):
  user_object = ndb.UserProperty(required=True, indexed=False)

class MyModel(EndPointModel):
  ...

    @MyModel.method(user_required=True, name="model.add", path="model")
    def add_mymodel(self, my_model):
      gplus_user_id = auth_util.get_google_plus_user_id()
      if gplus_user_id is None:
        raise endpoints.ForbiddenException(NidAppUser.NO_GPLUS_ID)

      user = MyUserClass.get_or_insert(gplus_user_id, user_object=endpoints.get_current_user())
      my_model.parent = user.key.string_id()
      my_model.put()
      return my_model 

    @MyModel.query_method(user_required=True, name="list.mymodel", path="models",
                          query_fields=('order','attr1',))
    def list_models(self, query):
      gplus_user_id = auth_util.get_google_plus_user_id()
      if gplus_user_id is None:
        raise endpoints.ForbiddenException(NidAppUser.NO_GPLUS_ID)

      ## Here or in thsi decorator function I want to do something like
      ## query.ancestor.(ndb.Key(MyClassUser, gplus_user_id)) (such as the DB Datastore)
      ## to return only the query of MyModels that belong to the current user
      return query
```

and I need to create a query ancestor by the key of MyUserClass key. I don't want to use the solution to add a field owner in my model because query ancestor is more fast than filters, and it really help me to organize my db.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a query based on ancestor like this:

```
myancestorkey = ndb.Key(MyUserClass, gplus_user_id)
myquery = MyModel.query(ancestor=myancestorkey)
```

Comment: Okay, Thank you but I mean if there is a way to use the query of EndPointModel and just to "update" it or to create a kind of filters for ancestors query and not to create a new one...

Comment: i did not completely understand your above comment. can you please explain?

Comment: In the method list_model I get as parameter an object query already created with the filters that I mentioned in the decorator. I want from this query to get only the rows that are the children of the ancestor "myancestorkey" and not to create a new query.

Answer (score 0):

With endpoints_proto_datastore you can do something like this:

```
@MyModel.query_method(user_required=True, name="list.mymodel",
                      path="models", query_fields=('order','attr1',))
def list_models(self, query):

    # Returns only MyModels that belong to the current g+ user

    return query.filter(MyModel.parent == auth_util.
                        get_google_plus_user_id())
```